# Two requests to two urls at once and I am not getting the data. [NodeJs API ]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to build an API that scrapes two different urls at once and sends a JSON response with information from those two urls.

The function below takes a url, makes a request to the url , searches for something and returns the array of that thing

```
function getData(url) {
    let data = [];
    request(url, (error,response,body) => {
         // Search for foo in the body
         data.push(foo);
    })
    return data;
}
```

And in the main function, I call the getData function twice with two different urls

```
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    let x = getData("myUrl/a");
    let y = getData("myUrl/b");
    let reply = {
        "a" : x,
        "b" : y
    }
    res.send(reply);    
})
```

This is basically what I wanna do with my API. But I am getting a blank object! I'm thinking it must be due to the asynchronous thing in JS which I'm not very familiar with.

What should I do to solve this?

**EDIT**

When I create two different routes and request only a single url, the API works fine

Comment: You can not return from a asynchronous call.

Comment: @epascarello didn't know that. But I have tried to store the data in a global variable and then return from the main route. It didn't work